# How to save the input from a radio input in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Hello I need your help to find a way to save my radio input and print it to the screen so I know that it is saved. I have this HTML:

```js
 if (document.getElementById('a1').checked) {
            rate_value1 = document.getElementById('a1').value;
            document.writeln(rate_value1); 
        }
        if (document.getElementById('a2').checked) {
            rate_value2 = document.getElementById('a2').value;
            document.writeln(rate_value2); 
        }
        if (document.getElementById('a3').checked) {
            rate_value3 = document.getElementById('a3').value;
            document.writeln(rate_value3); 
        }
        if (document.getElementById('a4').checked) {
            rate_value4 = document.getElementById('a4').value;
            document.writeln(rate_value4); 
        }
        if (document.getElementById('a5').checked) {
            rate_value5 = document.getElementById('a5').value;
            document.writeln(rate_value5); 
        }
```

```html
 <div class='input-form' id="div1">
        <h4 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Customize</h4>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="a5" ><label for="5">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="a4" ><label for="4">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="a3" ><label for="3">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="a2" ><label for="2">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="a1" ><label for="1">1</label>
    </div>
    <button type='button' id='but_add' value='Add new'>Add Rating Nums</button>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: When is this JS code run?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating another element above your `<div>` and target it whenever you click a radio button.

```
<p id="details"></p>

<div>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="a5" Onclick="display(this.value)" ><label >5</label>
</div>
```

In your js:

```
<script>

function display(x){

    document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = x;

}

</script>
```